# How to synchronize the Project Folder and same Project's folder in VS when we use SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am developing an Application in VS2012 and I am using SVN for it. 
We are 3-4 people working on same application so we have used SVN.

Now, some of our colleague added the new folder in the Project but I cant see at my end in VS, I can see it outside of VS in project folders but not in VS, though I refresh entire project and take update of View folder, still cant find the same folder in VS.

You can get idea by watching below pic...

[image]

How to synchronize it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... 
I have to click on show all files icon...
Newly added files from other people don't appear though we take update of the folder or refresh it...
We have to click on Show All Files Icon on Solution Explorer of VS and All the files added by other people will start appearing...
You have to right click on them and select the 'Include in Project'

Comment: OK. But then, after you include these files in the project, you could COMMIT YOUR PROJECT FILE TO SVN like I suggested in my answer. Then other people will use the same project and they won't need to add the same files manually.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio only knows about files and folders specifically added to its own project file. That project file should be added to SVN control if you want everybody to use the same project locations and settings.

Comment: ya, already added folder and file...but Cant see to other people... If I try to add the same folder and file in VS,  it showing folder already exist.

Comment: What does "can't see to other people" mean? Are you saying that in Visual Studio, you manually added the folder and file to your project, so that now you can see them in Visual Studio, but other people on your team still cannot see them?